# CSS highlight/selection color based on page focus

Tags: css, select, selector, highlight

So, this isn't an absolute need, but I am curious and might like to use it at some point if it exists...

I've developed a site (not my design) in which certain areas of text have a text-shadow, and I noticed that when said text is highlighted, it's not very legible.  I am aware of and utilizing the `::selection` CSS selector along with appropriate browser prefixes to remove the text-shadow on highlight.

My question is whether there's **anything that can override the highlighting defaults** when text remains selected and the **focus is removed from the page**?

Example: I do a select-all and by default (Mozilla), selected text gets a blue background.  I then ... say, start messing with Firebug, or open a smaller window over my browser.  All the highlights turn gray.  I can change the behavior of the blue with the `::selection` property (color, background, text-shadow, etc.), but the gray's behavior remains unchanged.  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@feelinferrety the answer is NO.

You can't change selection highlight colors on out-of-focus window. at least as of now (January 2019)

As this explains how to do it on focused window using `::selection` | `::-moz-selection` 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/

This clearly states that `:window-inactive` | `:-moz-window-inactive` will in fact work, BUT they don't work together ... because it's not standardized and therefore not developed 
https://css-tricks.com/window-inactive-styling/

Although interesting is that you can for example change background-color of half of the page when the window goes out of focus...

Comment: Thanks for citing up-to-date info and providing a specific article from everyone's favorite source for such CSS oddities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use selectors with the ::selection

for example try this for a specific paragraph with the class gray

```
.gray p::-moz-selection { color: gold;  background: red; }
.gray p::selection      { color: gold;  background: red; }
```

or even a div with the class gray

```
.gray div::-moz-selection { color: gold;  background: red; }
.gray div::selection      { color: gold;  background: red; }
```

I am not sure the compatibility with this but it works for me in FF, Chrome and IE9

Comment: text-shadow: none;

But i think his question was more about how to select specific elements with the ::selection he does say 

"I can change the behavior of the blue with the ::selection property (color, background, text-shadow, etc.)"

Comment: It's more about which defaults I'm able to override.  The ::selection property allows me to mess about with how a site visitor sees text that they have highlighted.  However, this override does not carry over when focus is removed from the site (but the page is still visible).